# How JUMP is decided based on the value of OUT-The ALU Output?

Tags: architecture, hardware, cpu-architecture, hdl, alu

[image: j1, j2 and j3 are bits for the jump instruction and comp instructions are the computation instructions like add etc.]

**Figure from The Elements of Computer System (Nand2Tetris)**

Have a look at the scenario where

```
 j1 = 1 (out < 0 )
 j2 = 0 (out = 0 )
 j3 = 1 (out > 0 )
```

How this scenario is possible as **out < 0** is true as well as **out > 0** but **out = 0** is false. How `out` can have both positive and negative values at the same time?

In other words when `JNE` instruction is going to execute although it theoretically seems possible to me but practically its not?